# Breaking a tie in python rock/paper/scissors with recursive function call

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I haven't seen a thread quite like this for python, specifically a recursive solution without human input. I have a network structure agent based model and the agents travel around the network, playing R/P/S when they meet. That part is fine.

What isn't working is having them play again upon a tie. My function for R/P/S:

```py
def rps(a, b): 
    moves = ['rock','paper','scissors']
    winner = 0
    a_c = random.choice(moves) # choice for a
    b_c = random.choice(moves) # choice for b
    while winner == 0: # Attempt to keep it going until a non-tie scenario
        if a_c == 'rock' and b_c == 'scissors':
            winner = a
        if a_c == 'rock' and b_c == 'paper':
            winner = b
        if a_c == 'rock' and b_c == 'rock':
            winner = rps(a,b) # Attempt at recursive call
        if a_c == 'scissors' and b_c == 'paper':
            winner = a
        if a_c == 'scissors' and b_c == 'rock':
            winner = b
        if a_c == 'scissors' and b_c == 'scissors':
            winner = rps(a,b)
        if a_c == 'paper' and b_c == 'rock':
            winner = a
        if a_c == 'paper' and b_c == 'scisssors':
            winner = b
        if a_c == 'paper' and b_c == 'paper':
            winner = rps(a,b)

    return winner
```

Originally I did not have the while loop and had ties set winner = 0, in which case the agents didn't move. However, forcing continued games within the function seemed easy conceptually. I tried testing with the following:

```py
for i in range(50):
    print(rps(1,2))
```

But upon the first tie, the loop is stuck. Help? I know this is a n00b question. I don't have a formal coding background and am learning as I go. Thank you very much for any explanation for what I'm inevitably doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```py
if a_c == 'paper' and b_c == 'scisssors':
```

contains an extra `s` in the condition checking `b_c`. If `a_c` is `'paper'` and `b_c` is `'scissors'`, then none of the cases will match, and your code will loop infinitely.

Instead, use:

```py
if a_c == 'paper' and b_c == 'scissors':
```

(As an aside, you don't need the `while` loop, because you're using recursion to play another round on a tie.)

Comment: That is an embarrassingly dumb mistake but I just couldn't see it. Thank you.